# DynamoDB with Supertest (Intermittent failures)

Tags: continuous-integration, amazon-dynamodb, integration-testing, supertest, amazon-dynamodb-local

Im testing a small api project with CRUD endpoints. I run all my tests using supertest to check my calls all work on local DynamoDB. The issue is, when I run these tests they randomly all pass or one fails. It's rarely the same one that fails but it's always only one.

Any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: Have you checked throttled requests metric?

Comment: I'll look into that.

Comment: @mokugo-devops it seems that works with Cloudwatch, but I'm on local using a docker-hub version of dynamo. Is that the only way to check those metrics?